# Attempting to implement a websocket client from (mostly)scratch, having trouble connecting to websocket servers

Tags: rust, websocket

```
se std::sync::Arc;
use rand::Rng;
use rustls::{pki_types::ServerName, ClientConfig, RootCertStore};
use tokio::{io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt}, net::{lookup_host, TcpSocket}};
use tokio_rustls::TlsConnector;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let nonce = generate_nonce();
    let host = "echo.websocket.org";
    let port = 443;
    let path = "/";
    let addr = format!("{}:{}", host, port);
    let addr = lookup_host(addr).await.unwrap().next().unwrap();
    let socket = TcpSocket::new_v4().unwrap();
    let mut stream = socket.connect(addr).await.unwrap();
    let server_name = ServerName::try_from(host).unwrap();
    let mut tls = get_tls_connector().connect(server_name, &mut stream).await.unwrap();
    let mut write_string = String::new();
    write_string.push_str(format!("GET {} HTTP/1.1\r\n", path).as_str());
    write_string.push_str(format!("Host: {}\r\n", host).as_str());
    write_string.push_str("Connection: Upgrade\r\n");
    write_string.push_str("Upgrade: websocket\r\n");
    write_string.push_str(format!("Sec-WebSocket-Key: {}\r\n", nonce).as_str());
    write_string.push_str("Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n");
    write_string.push_str("\r\n");
    tls.write_all(write_string.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
    tls.flush().await.unwrap();
    let mut read_str = String::new();
    let _size = tls.read_to_string(&mut read_str).await.unwrap();
    println!("{}", read_str);
    read_str.clear();
}

fn generate_nonce() -> String {
    let r: [u8; 16] = rand::random();
    data_encoding::BASE64.encode(&r)
}

fn get_tls_connector() -> TlsConnector {
    let mut root_store = RootCertStore::empty();
    root_store.extend(webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS
    .iter()
    .cloned()
    );
    let config = ClientConfig::builder()
    .with_root_certificates(root_store)
    .with_no_client_auth();
    let rc_config = Arc::new(config);
    TlsConnector::from(rc_config)
}
```

I'm new to Rust and am attempting to connect to an echo websocket server. However I do not seem to be able to get it to send an upgrade response. Perhaps do I need to specify a scheme somehow? I'm running out of ideas lol. Oddly if I remove the "Upgrade: Websocket" line it does give me a 200 response so the server exists and the raw socket can open and communicate. I've tried a few other websocket echo servers as well and for some reason none of them like my request/headers. Postman is also ok with connecting to echo.websocket.org and copying there headers doesn't appear to work either. It's late so I'm probably missing something but if anyone can point me in the right direction I'd sure appreciate it =)

Edit: as per suggestions in the comments I've updated my base64 nonce generator to eliminate any issues to the same method that tungstenite uses:
https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs/blob/0fa41973b4c075f5d4a9e03a82a26a301ca31ce9/src/handshake/client.rs#L278
crate added: data-encryption

sidenote: going to have to build my own base 64 encoder next! Legit excited

for anyone coming along later looking down a similar path, my problem was that read_to_string was looking for an EOF but a server won't provide that with a websocket, I needed to break it down by \r\n lines but thankfully tokio provides a helper via the bufreader. Below is updated main function, the nonce and connector above are the same. Note that this code is nothing approaching production ready but it's a fun learn.

```
use std::sync::Arc;

use rustls::{pki_types::ServerName, ClientConfig, RootCertStore};
use tokio::{io::{split, AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader}, net::{lookup_host, TcpSocket}};
use tokio_rustls::TlsConnector;


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let nonce = generate_nonce();
    let host = "echo.websocket.org";
    let port = 443;
    let path = "/";
    let addr = format!("{}:{}", host, port);
    let addr = lookup_host(addr).await.unwrap().next().unwrap();
    let socket = TcpSocket::new_v4().unwrap();
    let mut stream = socket.connect(addr).await.unwrap();
    let server_name = ServerName::try_from(host).unwrap();
    let tls = get_tls_connector().connect(server_name, &mut stream).await.unwrap();
    let (reader, mut writer) = split(tls);
    let mut write_string = String::new();
    write_string.push_str(format!("GET {} HTTP/1.1\r\n", path).as_str());
    write_string.push_str(format!("Host: {}\r\n", host).as_str());
    write_string.push_str("Connection: Upgrade\r\n");
    write_string.push_str("Upgrade: websocket\r\n");
    write_string.push_str(format!("Sec-WebSocket-Key: {}\r\n", nonce).as_str());
    write_string.push_str("Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n");
    //write_string.push_str("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n");
    write_string.push_str("\r\n");
    writer.write_all(write_string.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
    writer.flush().await.unwrap();
    let mut lines = BufReader::new(reader).lines();
    loop {
        let line = lines.next_line().await.unwrap().unwrap();
        println!("{}", line);
        if line.is_empty() {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing according to [the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455)?

Comment: @tadmad attempting to yea, encoding of data frames and such is already done too (though if that doesn't work I'll be back! lol) it's just odd to me that this won't connect as I've implemented it in other languages.

Comment: It's worth looking for a conformance testing tool if such a thing exists. It might highlight errors or oversights in your implementation.

Comment: yea if I had such things I'd be all over analyzing this lol

Comment: Your nonce generation could be simplified significantly by using the method that [`tungstenite` uses](https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs/blob/0fa41973b4c075f5d4a9e03a82a26a301ca31ce9/src/handshake/client.rs#L278-L283), which generates 16 random bytes and encodes it to base64. You may want to reference how `tungstenite` performs their handshake in general. [Here's where it starts](https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs/blob/0fa41973b4c075f5d4a9e03a82a26a301ca31ce9/src/client.rs#L155-L165).

Comment: I converted a nonce generator written in JavaScript so it's probably not the cleanest =)  but it does implement the logic found in the rfc(as near as I can tell): "The value of this header field MUST be a nonce consisting of a randomly selected 16-byte value that has been base64-encoded" in this case being generated from the characters in sample_chars =) 
With tungstenite and even fastwebsockets I'm seeing a bunch of the problem being abstracted into url and http crates(trying to avoid anymore crates) which given I'm generating everything by hand seems erroneous

Comment: @Nicholas Crothers followup: holy heck tungstenite's nonce implementation is easier! Alas it's that extra crate thing lol(I'm ok with those later down the road) If I can get this whole thing to work this gets me even more excited about Rust

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `read_to_string`? That waits for EOF so I think that's very much not what you want. You're probably getting back the upgrade header and then it's blocking trying to read any incoming websocket frames. You probably need to read chunks one at a time until you find a `\r\n`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ok, I shall go in and give that a shot! Updated code in a bit.

Comment: @loganfsmyth if you could please do me a favor and post this as an Answer then as soon as I can accept it I will =) It's working splendidly now yea, mistake on my part for that EOF and not parsing the CRLF, thankfully the tokio bufreader lines function splits specifically at CRLF's so good to go! I will update with the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work overall, but there's one small issue! You have

```
let mut read_str = String::new();
let _size = tls.read_to_string(&mut read_str).await.unwrap();
println!("{}", read_str);
```

however `read_to_string` reads *all* data from the stream, where in your case you only want to read until you find an empty line (the end of the HTTP response header). You can't wait for an EOF because a websocket is a persistent socket, and after the `\r\n` the stream will transition into a channel for websocket frames, and will not be closed.

As you've noted, one way to do that would be to use a Tokio's `Lines` iterator with [`AsyncBufReadExt#lines`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncBufReadExt.html#method.lines), e.g.

```
let mut lines = BufReader::new(reader).lines();

// ...
loop {
    let line = lines.next_line().await.unwrap().unwrap();
    println!("{}", line);
    if line.is_empty() {
        break;
    }
}
```

though note that if you go this route, then processing later websocket frames could become more complicated because `lines` has internal buffers that could have already processed a portion of a websocket frame, if it were sent immediately after the response headers, and from what I can see there's no easy way to extract that data.

If you intend to continue building a websocket frame parser, you may be better off using [`AsyncBufReadExt#read_until`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncBufReadExt.html#method.read_until) to read up to a `\n`. That would require a bit more work, but not a ton.

Comment: Oh an approach suggestion too! I shall give that a shot later, thank you again!